# Determining Optoisolator HCNR201 isolation voltage

Tags: current-measurement, opto-isolator, high-voltage, isolation

I am working on a project in which I was required to use an opto-isolator. The problem is that I am confused which parameter should I consider from the datasheet of opto-isolator HCNR201, in order to determine the maximum isolation voltage:

- Maximum Working Insulation Voltage
- Input to Output Test Voltage method_b
- Input to Output Test Voltage method_a

The schematic of the circuit is given below. The only change is that instead of 1kV, I am required to use 3kV.

[image: Current Measurement]

Snippet from the datasheet is given below:

[image: HCNR201]

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question about the *performance* of a device, but about its *ratings*. The difference between the two is *safety factor*.

If it is you, alone, testing this optocoupler under controlled conditions, or using it in a situation where nobody else would come across it, then you could put 2121v (test method a), 2651v (test method b) or even 8000v (highest allowable) across it, for the limited test times specified in the data sheet.

If anybody else will come into contact with equipment using this device (family, customers, school mates) or you are going to power it indefinitely, then you should observe the Maximum Working Insulation Voltage of 1414v peak (1000v AC sinewave). The school have every right to insist upon operating things within their ratings. You would be morally responsible (and either you or the school legally responsible depending on jurisdiction and details) in the (probably) unlikely event of anybody being harmed as a result of its failure. The school's insurance cover would almost certainly be void in the event of them allowing you to use a safety critical device outside its rated conditions.